# How can I get the value in an array of array Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var data=[
           {
              'Name':'Yash',
              'PhoneNo':['123456','654123']
           },
           {
              'Name':'Rahul',
              'PhoneNo':['789456','789456']
           }
         ];

for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
 {
    alert(data[i].PhoneNo.length);
    for(j=0;j<data[i].PhoneNo.length;j++)   
    {
      alert(data[i][j].PhoneNo);
    }
```

How can I access value from an array 'Phone' from an object data ? 
    I tried like this,but its not working.
Thank You in Advance

Comment: Where did you get "PhoneNo" from? :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data=[
    {
        'Name':'Yash',
        'Phone':['123456','654123']
    },
    {
        'Name':'Rahul',
        'Phone':['789456','789456']
    }
];

for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    alert(data[i].Phone.length);
    for(j=0;j<data[i].Phone.length;j++)   
    {
      alert(data[i].Phone[j]);
    }
}
```

Replaced `PhoneNo` with `Phone` and `alert(data[i][j].Phone);` with `alert(data[i].Phone[j]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
 {
    alert(data[i].Phone.length);
    for(j=0;j<data[i].Phone.length;j++)   
    {
      alert(data[i].Phone[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, it might help people to add some more explanation or comments to your answer.

Comment: Can we assign that array values to the text boxes.If more numbers are there ,the numbers should assigned to the number of text boxes.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Do you mean html text boxes? do you want to create them dynamically?